# .NET 6, Web API - configuration driven DI and NuGet package registration

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, nuget, appsettings

I'm using .NET 6 Web API and would like to introduce some custom mocking NuGet package to our dev/test environments. I don't want this package/code to be present in further stages, so would like to do some DI registration in the appsettings.json instead of Program.cs. Would be nice to load NuGet package containing mock code as well from the appsettings.json. This would give the control of the environment via its configuration file. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding DI registration, you should be able to put part of configuration into configuration file. How exactly can it be done depends on the DI container. E.g. here is the doc for Autofac: https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/xml.html

But I don't think you can or should do similar trick for NuGet packages.